How to distinguish AltGr and Ctrl+RAlt programmatically (osk.exe does it somehow)
As is known, in most keyboard national layouts, the right Alt key functions as AltGr. However, AltGr is not a "real" key; it doesn't have a specific VirtualKeyCode/ScanCode, and programmatically its depression appears as two separate sequential presses:

Left Ctrl
Right Alt

Multiple discussions on Stack Overflow pertain to this, but so far, no one has proposed a way to programmatically distinguish whether AltGr is currently being pressed or if it's a combination of LCtrl+RAlt.
At the same time, there is reason to believe that it is possible, given that the OSK (On-Screen Keyboard, C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe) application differentiates between them. This can be easily verified by experimenting with key presses and observing corresponding key changes on the screen.
So, the question remains open: How can one differentiate between AltGr and LCtrl+RAlt programmatically?
I attempted to observe the sequence of events triggered by pressing AltGr, looking for any characteristic features in the structure of INPUT_RECORD.
I also tried to ascertain the status of the VK_LCONTROL, VK_RCONTROL, VK_LMENU, VK_RMENU keys through GetKeyState. However, I did not find anything specific to AltGr that could distinguish it from pressing LCtrl+RAlt.
Nevertheless, the On-Screen Keyboard (OSK) somehow resolves this issue. For instance, you can press (and hold) Ctrl+AltGr and it will show that the keys have been pressed individually.
P.S.
Please note that there is a similar question at Windows: Detect if right alt generates Ctrl+Alt (AltGr) in current layout.
However, that question is slightly different: it inquires about how to discern if a keyboard layout treats RAlt as AltGr. Here, on the other hand, I am trying to figure out something slightly different.

The right Alt key is equivalent to the AltGr key (same as Scancode). If you don't have the right Alt key, you can use Ctrl + Left Alt to emulate the AltGr key combination and Shift + Ctrl + Left Alt to emulate the Shift + AltGr key combination in Windows.
You can test it in United Kingdom Keyboard.

